# How should I know what classpath to set on a Gradle build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I mostly do devops work. I'm setting up Jenkins for a team. They have a Kotlin project that they are buidling on their local machines with Gradle. I have never worked with Kotlin or Gradle, but I have worked with Java.

The code compiles for them. They use the shadowjar plugin, so they create an uberjar. I just need to get this going on the new Jenkins server that I set up for them.

If I ssh to the Jenkins server (a fresh AWS EC2 which I just setup with Terraform) and if I git clone the repo (just to debug what I need in order for it to build on this server) I can do this:

```
gradle build
```

I get:

```
:buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.742 secs
```

So I think maybe it wants me to set the classpath? What should the classpath be?

This file:

```
cat build.gradle.kts
```

Seems reasonably complete, and seems to have everything:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    application
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.3"
}

group = "com.sugar"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.11.2")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.10")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.0")
    compile("org.postgresql", "postgresql", "42.2.5")
    implementation("com.github.ajalt:clikt:1.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClassName = "bees.BeesKt"
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    baseName = "bees.fat"
    classifier = ""
    version = ""
}
```

I did read setup guides like this one:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/#scratch

But they are both very long and they have not answered any of the basic questions that I have.

Any help most welcome!

Comment: Did the developers not give you build directions?

Comment: Should they? I was assuming if they gave me a working build file there was probably some simple CLI commands I could run to get it going. I was expecting some like "gradle install dependencies" and then "gradle build". But I've read a lot of tutorials and I've to see which CLI commands I'm supposed to run.

Comment: A developer who is actually familiar with this might be able to sort it in five seconds. It appears you've already covered the obvious stuff, so it might be a good idea.

Comment: I asked the developers. They don't know how to build this. They rely on their IDE. They use IntelliJ, which handles the details for them. So I need to figure out the CLI part on my own.

Comment: Nothing at all? The response to this question makes me nervous. And yet, people surely use Gradle in Jenkins. I'm puzzled why it is so hard to find the right information.

Comment: Well, this is something developers usually do, and you're on a site for ops. Few people here go this far into dev. You might do better with this question at [so].